# Complex analysis for generating functions

Tags: complex-analysis, generating-functions

Looking at "Generatingfunctionology" by Wilf, it seems that complex analysis is quite useful when it comes to finding asymptotic approximations. However, what prerequisites from complex analysis are actually needed? I've seen that Cauchy's theorem is used quite often, but is there anything apart from it that is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A great, user-friendly introduction to all the necessary prerequisites we need from complex analysis together with a wealth of applications is presented in part B of *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

Each of the chapters IV - VIII

- IV:  Complex Analysis, rational and meromorphic asymptotics
- V:       Applications of rational and meromorphic asymptotics
- VI: Singularity Analysis of generating functions
- VII: Applications of singularity analysis
- VIII:    Saddle-point asymptotics

starts with explanatory sections and cites resp. derives the theorems needed to understand the given applications.